# Relative path in a PHP project

Tags: php, path, include

I'm working on a PHP project, and I have a problem with a file path in a require_once.

The folder structure for the 2 files is this:

**- Library**

- Example

  - ***currentpage***
- HTML2PDF

  - ***file to include***

in the "currentpage" I have a

```
require_once ('../HTML2PDF/html2pdf.class.php');
```

but it gives me this error:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

What am I missing?

Comment: add your absolute path of the file like require_once ('var/www/HTML2PDF/html2pdf.class.php');

Comment: you could also do something like `require_once(getcwd().'/../HTML2PDF/html2pdf.class.php');'`

Answer (score 3):

try

```
require_once (__DIR__ . '/../HTML2PDF/html2pdf.class.php');
```

as it will give you the absolute path for the current file

Answer (score 2):

You can define a global application root in a central configuration file. Say you have `config.php` in your app root. Then do a

```
define("APP_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));
```

you still have to include the config file, and you have to use relative paths for it, e.g.

```
include ("../../../config.php");
```

but once you have done that, you can work relative to the app root inside the script:

```
include (APP_ROOT."/b.php");  <--  Will always return the correct path
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your currentpage is itself called by another page (let's call it page3).

And in page3, the relative file path `../HTML2PDF/html2pdf.class.php` can not be found, because it's a relative path for currentpage.

You should use file relative paths :

```
require_once (__DIR__ . '/../HTML2PDF/html2pdf.class.php');
```

or

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../HTML2PDF/html2pdf.class.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're `require`'ing a file that, obviously, contains a class definition. *"managing"* the requires manually is all well and good for small projects, but as your project grows, and as your writing code that depends on some classes being available in different files, you'll find yourself in a right pickle. Please, please, use an *autoloader*!
There's a really easy to use, and handy function for this, too: `spl_autoload_register`, [the docs are quite easy to understand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

You can create this autoloader in a single file, say in your project root, and define a constant, let's call it `PROJECT_ROOT`:

```
define('PROJECT_ROOT', realpath(__DIR__).'/');
```

From there on, you *know* where your classes are, which directories to look in, and what the filenames look like. Suppose I have a class called `DB_Mapper`, the function could look like:

```
function myAutoloader($class)
{
    $path = implode('/',explode('_', $class));
    $path .= '.class.php';
    if (file_exists($path)) require $path;
    else throw new RuntimeException($class.' not found @'.$path);
}
```

But that's just a basic example...

Answer (score 0):

You can set path in your config file.

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='127.0.0.1') { // If you are working in local server
        define("PATH",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/[Folder Name]/'); 
        define("URL","http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/[Folder Name]/'); 
        }
        else {
        define("PATH",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'); 
        define("URL","http://".str_replace('www.','',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']).'/'); 
        }

    and you can call

 require_once (PATH.'HTML2PDF/html2pdf.class.php');
```